# Flex, get USB id of plugged USB device

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, air

I'm developping an Adobe Flex application.

I need to detect gps devices when plugged.
Currently, it is a bad heuristic-based detection that is used (it tries to find specific files/directories). It uses the StorageVolumeInfo to discover plugged devices.

Thus, I'd like to know if there's a way to get the USB id with Flex.

Thx in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Right now, no, you can't do it natively in Air.  You could however use a third party utility application to communicate with the device (java, c++, etc).  Air USB device controls will be coming eventually after Adobe did a demo of using an xbox controller to play a game.

I tried looking for a release date, but to no avail.

Comment: Thx :) (Even if this is bad news.)

Comment: I wouldn't say bad news.  It's not impossible, it's just not easy currently and will be made available natively later :)

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the functionality you are looking for is only available in AIR.
The following example shows all currently connected device names when starting up and also adds an event listener for devices that are connected at runtime.

```
        import mx.events.FlexEvent;

        private function onCreationComplete(e:FlexEvent):void{
            StorageVolumeInfo.storageVolumeInfo.addEventListener(StorageVolumeChangeEvent.STORAGE_VOLUME_MOUNT,onMount);
            showCurrentlyConnectedVolumes();

        }

        private function onMount(event:StorageVolumeChangeEvent):void{
            trace(event.storageVolume.name);
        }

        private function showCurrentlyConnectedVolumes():void{
            for each(var volume:StorageVolume in StorageVolumeInfo.storageVolumeInfo.getStorageVolumes()){
                trace(volume.name);
            }
        }
```

Cheers

Comment: As stated, I already have access to the plugged devices. Yet, I need to get the USB id (as when you type lsusb on Linux).

Comment: In that case I guess you will have to resort to more drastic solutions.

I do not know a lot of c/c++ but you could try getting more information through Alchemy http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/alchemy/
It is a particularly nice solution because the alchemy code will compile to an .swc file you can embed into your application.